# Android Car Unit - Touchscreen not working after ignition off and reboot

Tags: reboot, touchscreen

I have an Android 9 radio from Klyde (CSN2_D, PX5, Rockchip rk3368). There is a power-saving feature that cuts most of power consumption after 30 sec. when ignition is off (do you call this deep sleep?). Technically yellow main power cable stays connected, red ignition power cable is cut. When I start the car the unit reboots.

My problem: Touchscreen does not work after boot. This happens only with this mode. Forcing reboot from the unit or from stock recovery or rebooting after all power cables were cut works fine. Same problem when unit is removed from the car, so it is not a wiring issue.

The problem occurrs since I tried a different launcher and removed it. It looks like this launcher changed some settings which remained permanently saved, because FM radio stations that were stored at that moment are permanently stored in the unit as well.

I tried a lot:

- Firmware update Android 9
- Upgrade to Android 10
- MCU update with different versions
- Factory and cache reset
- Complete new installation with Rockchips' AndroidTool after forcing unit in Maskrom mode
- Erase flash with AndroidTool and new installation

I saved dmesg.log-files and here is the difference:

Working:

```
[    0.907815] of_get_named_gpiod_flags: parsed 'touch-gpio' property of node '/i2c@ff140000/gt9xx_main@14[0]' - status (0)
[    0.907841] of_get_named_gpiod_flags: parsed 'reset-gpio' property of node '/i2c@ff140000/gt9xx_main@14[0]' - status (0)
[    1.004583] Goodix-TS 2-0014: GTP X_MAX: 1024, Y_MAX: 600, TRIGGER: 0x01
[    1.016532] GTP Sensor_ID: 0
[    1.016554] ## GTP: 1024x600 customer touch type: -1 ; customer type1125 index: -1
[    1.016792] input: goodix-ts as /devices/platform/ff140000.i2c/i2c-2/2-0014/input/input1
```

No touchscreen:

```
[    0.909817] of_get_named_gpiod_flags: parsed 'touch-gpio' property of node '/i2c@ff140000/gt9xx_main@14[0]' - status (0)
[    0.909843] of_get_named_gpiod_flags: parsed 'reset-gpio' property of node '/i2c@ff140000/gt9xx_main@14[0]' - status (0)
[    0.995911] <<-GTP-ERROR->> I2C Read: 0x8140, 6 bytes failed, errcode: -6! Process reset.
[    1.071450] <<-GTP-ERROR->> GTP read version failed
[    1.123893] <<-GTP-ERROR->> I2C Read: 0x8140, 6 bytes failed, errcode: -6! Process reset.
[    1.168453] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-platform
[    1.199449] <<-GTP-ERROR->> GTP read version failed
[    1.199471] <<-GTP-ERROR->> Read version failed.
```

- [dmesg.log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N8TWXrFoGxvPumhxUAozXotdn2EDmfh2/view?usp=sharing) (crashed)
- [dmesg.log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19i8fcykAAb2a-dYeJWyz4hvnSXHil0wK/view?usp=sharing) (working)

Any ideas what happened and how I can solve the problem?

Comment: The entry `I2C Read: 0x8140, 6 bytes failed, errcode: -6` indicates that the communication on hardware level (using I2C bus system) does not work correctly. That the problems started when you changed the launcher may be coincidence, especially as you have performed a factory reset and more.

Comment: Okay, but shouldn't a hardware problem occur always and not only while rebooting from deep sleep?